# Show search results as an iframe lightbox in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, lightbox

I have a search bar on a page I'm developing. It works well but I'm just wondering what the best way would be to have the search result open in an iframe lightbox on the same page, rather than in a new page. I have some experience with iframes and lightboxes, but not with doing that in jQuery.

My jQuery/HTML is as follows.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.submit_on_enter').keydown(function (event) {
            // enter has keyCode = 13, change it if you want to use another button
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                this.form.q.value = this.form.q.value + " site:tecior.com"
                this.form.submit();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outercontain">
    <div class="innercontain" align="center">
        <form action="https://duckduckgo.com/" target="_blank" method="get">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="submit_on_enter" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Art"
                onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Search Art'">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi Raphael. Stackoverflow is generally reserved for questions about a specific issue. You don’t seem to have one as it’s working well. There are other stack exchange sites like [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) who can help you navigate what’s good or bad practices.

Comment: No, it doesn't work well for an iframe lightbox - it works well if I just want it to open in a new page. I don't have a solution at all for making this open in an iframe lightbox - which is what I'm looking to do. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Try using fancybox (https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/), it has "auto-size" feature for iframes.

Comment: That definitely looks interesting Janis - but I don't have the technical expertise on how to actually open my search result with it. I've managed to embed it to my site but it only opens predefined links onclick. I need it to open my search result on pressing the enter key... Maybe you could help me with that?

Comment: Use API to start fancybox from within form submit event, like `$.fancybox.open({ src : 'searchPage.php?query=' + something, type: 'iframe'});`